# Find the nearest price of a number in csv file

Tags: python

I have a csv file that has a list of cars. I want to give the best car recommendation for the price the user inputs. If the user input 93850, it would find 3 cars that are closest to that price if it doesn't have that price.

My Code is:

```
import csv
    with open('carlist.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        # skip header
        next(reader, None)
        # assign car list
        carlist = list(reader)

Carcost = float(input("Car cost:"))
AnualInterest = float(input("Anual Interest"))
loandur = int(input("Loan duration:"))


#The total amount of months of the loan
loanmonth = loandur * 12

# vehicle tax
CarTax = Carcost * 0.12 + Carcost

# interest rate
interest = AnualInterest / ( 100 * 12 )

# monthly repayment
monthpayment = CarTax * ( interest * ( ( interest + 1 ) ** loanmonth ) ) / ( ( interest + 1 ) ** loanmonth - 1 )

# vehicles in price range
VehiclesInRange = []

# get the price list from the csv
PriceList = [row[0] for row in carlist]

# get the closest value vehicle
ClosestValueVehicle = min(PriceList, key=lambda x:abs(int(x)-Carcost))

print(ClosestValueVehicle)

for row in carlist:
    # price
    price = row[0]
    # check if price in range
    if int(price) == int(ClosestValueVehicle) and VehiclesInRange.count < 3:
       VehiclesInRange.append(row)

print("Vehicle Recomendations:")

# print list of vehicles in price range
for vehicle in VehiclesInRange:

    print('%s %s %s (VIN: %s) (Millage:%s) (Location: %s, %s) - $%s' % 
        ( vehicle[1], 
          vehicle[2], 
          vehicle[7], 
          vehicle[5], 
          vehicle[2], 
          vehicle[3], 
          vehicle[4], 
          str('{:,}'.format(int(vehicle[0]))) ) )
```

My CSV file:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/kcx1xzx3hued54y/carlist.csv/file#!

I check if the list has less than 3 items than keep appending but it doesn't work. Also right now it's checking for the exact price. If I enter a number like 93850, I want it to  show me 3 that are closest to 93850 even though there's only one car with the price of 93850.

Comment: You should use pandas

Comment: I dont know what is panda, a module? A language?

Comment: Its a python module you can install by doing pip install pandas

Answer (score 1):

Try it using pandas to install in run this command :

```
pip install pandas
```

Here is an example of what you can do with pandas :

```
import pandas
#read your file
df = pandas.read_csv('carlist.csv')

#print your dataframe
print(df)
#print the price column
print(df['Price'])
#get rows where price is equal to 8995
print(df.loc[df['Price'] == 8995])
```

And to get the nearest price as mrzo said you can do this :

```
print(df.iloc[(df['Price']-8995).abs().argsort()])
```

Comment: You can use `df.iloc[(df['Price']-8895).abs().argmin()]` to find the nearest price.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `heapq` module from the standard library.

```
import heapq
...
ClosestValueVehicle = heapq.nsmallest(3, PriceList, lambda x: abs(float(x) - CarCost))
```

You will get a list with the 3 values from `PriceList`which are closest to `CarCost`

Comment: It gave me an error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Comment: `PriceList` is a list of strings: you have to convert the string to a float, either the full list if you use values later, or like here when you use the values. Post edited.

Comment: How do I convert the full list into float? I did float(PriceList) = [row[0] for row in carlist]

Comment: @JustinGrave: time to learn the basics of Python ;-). The idiomatic way is `PriceList = [float(row[0]) for row in carlist]`

Comment: Still got an error, this time it says if int(price) == int(ClosestValueVehicle):
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'. I put your code up top.

Comment: @JustinGrave: Can you read what I have written in my answer: *You will get a list with the 3 values...*. You asked for the 3 closest value, and I cannot store 3 different values into one single scalar variable. I think you want `if int(price) == int(ClosestValueVehicle[0])`

Comment: I did it didn't show three closest value for me can you show me what I did wrong https://www.mediafire.com/file/35ehzvyvm2tngoe/carloan.py/file. I'm dragging the file into the cmd terminal

Answer (score 0):

I have used dictionaries to allow you to search a car's information by its price, and allow you to search a car's price by its difference in price compared to the one the user enters. My solution will output the closest three cars, in price, to the one the user enters. Let me know if you have any further questions as to how it works. Also, I removed your extra code that wasn't exactly related to your question.

```
import csv
with open('carlist.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    # skip header
    next(reader, None)
    # assign car list
    carlist = list(reader)

Carcost = float(input("Car cost: "))

# the car price is the key and the car info is the value
PriceList = {int(row[0]): row for row in carlist}

# the difference in cost is the key and the actual car cost is the value
ClosestValueDict = {abs(x-Carcost): x for x in list(PriceList.keys())}

# sort all the cost differences in a list
CostDiffList = sorted(ClosestValueDict)

print("Here are 3 vehicles close to your preferred price of %d..." % Carcost)
for i in range(0, 3, 1):
    diff = CostDiffList[i]
    cost = ClosestValueDict[diff]
    print(PriceList[cost])
```

Here is an example input and output when I ran it...

> Car cost: 93850
>
> Here are 3 vehicles close to your preferred price of 93850...
>
> ['93850', '2014', '12135', 'Fishers', ' IN', 'SALGV2TF2EA191989', 'Land', 'Rover']
>
> ['93880', '2018', '1635', 'Torrance', ' CA', 'JTHHP5AY1JA000633', 'Lexus', 'LCLC']
>
> ['93884', '2015', '18617', 'Montclair', ' CA', 'WP0AB2A99FS124059', 'Porsche', '911Coupe']